# install SQLite on a USB stick attached to a Linux/Debian box

Tags: sqlite

I need my application to run from a USB stick and perform the installation from there.
The application is eventually installed on a Linux/Debian.
For the application installation I need a DB to be installed on that USB. I also need the DB data (tables, etc.) to be kept on that USB stick.

I read that SQLite is a good candidate to be used for such a purpose. However, I could no find the steps needed for installing it on the USB stick.

I did download the sqlite-snapshot-202002271621.tar.gz from the sqlite.org site, placed it in one of my Debian directories and used the 3 commands to install it (./configure,make,make install). 
That installed SQLite on my hard disk.

What should I do in order to achieve the same on the USB stick?
Mount the USB to the Debian box, place the tar.gz file there, and run the commands from there?
Will that install SQLite on the USB?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

So the answer is indeed:
Mount the USB to the Debian box
Place the sqlite-snapshot-202002271621.tar.gz file there
Run the commands from there
./configure
make
make install

Notice just that I had to tar the sqlite-snapshot-202002271621.tar.gz file using:
tar -zvxf sqlite-snapshot-202002271621.tar.gz -C /media/usbstick/ --no-same-owner

In order to avoid the error:
"Cannot change ownership to uid 1000, gid 1000: Operation not permitted"